# Zipping all files in a folder but excluding all subfolders

Tags: zip

I would like to zip all files in a given folder but none of the directories: any idea on how to do it?

e.g. directory **X** contains files **F1** and **F2** and directories **D1** and **D2**.
How can I zip directory **X** to only have **F1** and **F2** and not **D1** and **D2**.

Comment: Please use proper syntax

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `find` or compatible, assuming there are no filenames containing newlines:

```
find X -maxdepth 1 -type f | zip -nw -@ X.zip
```

The `-@` option takes a list of files from stdin, one file per line. `-nw` (or `--no-wild`) turns off wildcard expansion by `zip`, to avoid problems with filenames containing `*`, `?` or `[` characters.

Comment: smart ! there is no easier way ?? A flag, a wildcard, etc ?

Comment: Maybe with `zsh`? I don't know a faster way, let's wait for other answers.

Comment: @user3360735 it's already extremely compact and optimised

Answer (score 2):

One way to approach it would be to use `zip`'s exclusion option:

```
zip /path/to/zip/file.zip /path/to/given/folder/* -x /path/to/given/folder/*/
```

This tells `zip` to archive everything in /path/to/given/folder but also to exclude everything in that folder that is a directory. Here it's the shell doing the work, via wildcards, to expand the wildcard that ends in slash to the list of directories in that folder. If you had dotfiles in that directory, you'd have to expand them separately -- and also exclude any "dot directories".

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`,

```
zip -nw X.zip X X/*(ND.)
```

Would store `X` and the regular files (with the `.` *glob qualifier* including hidden ones with `D`) in it into the `X.zip` compressed archive in lexical order.

Instead of `.` which selects *regular* files only, you could use `^/` which selects files of any type *except* directories, including symlink, fifo, devices, sockets. But of those, the zip format (which is not much of a Unix format) can only store symlinks and fifos (named pipes), and you'd need to pass the `--symlinks` and `--fifo` option to `zip`. You could also use `.,@,p` to select only regular, symlinks and named `p`ipes:

```
zip --symlinks --fifo -nw X.zip X/*(ND.,@,p)
```

Answer (score -1):

In case we want to escape a specific subfolder at time to zip, we need to scape the `*` with a backslash (`\`), so that it is treated as a literal character by the shell (rather than being expanded into a list of files), in this way:

```
zip /path/to/zip/file.zip /path/to/given/folder/* -x /path/to/given/folder/subfolder/\*
```

Hope this help!

Comment: If the `*` is not escaped or quoted somehow, it will be expanded by the shell. However, this would still work correctly since the `-x` option takes one _or several_ patterns.  The trailing `/` is needed to only match directories.

Comment: Yes, you're right...
Sorry, I tried and posted my answer for the case of escaping a specific subfolder, I missed that the question mentioned 'all subfolders'.
Editing my comment, in case this still helpful for someone.